# display the rows based on the last occurrence of an element in a column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

display the rows based on last occurrence of row based on matching values in qty and name column. I would like to drop the rows which does not match the criteria.

before:

```
    name   qty  price
0   Adam    10    1  
1   Rose    11    9
2   Jack    10     12
3   Jack    5     11
4   Rose    15    4
5   Jack    12    17
6   Adam    10    8
7   Rose    11    4
8   Jack    6     23
5   Jack    12    9
    Jack    10    4
```

after:

```
    name   qty  price
0   Jack    5     11
1   Rose    15    4
2   Adam    10    8
3   Rose    11    4
4   Jack    6     23
5   Jack    12    9
6   Jack    10    4
```

Comment: order in which the rows are display does not matter to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to get the last occurrence of each name, qty grouping.

```
df.groupby(['name', 'qty'], as_index=False).last()


   name  qty  price
0  Adam   10      8
1  Jack    5     11
2  Jack    6     23
3  Jack   10      4
4  Jack   12      9
5  Rose   11      4
6  Rose   15      4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.